# Using a block in Object-C, I get "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)"

Tags: objective-c

I want to add GestureRecognizer on an imageView and use a block in the clickAction.

But when I run it, I get this error in the block:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)

```
#import "blockImage.h"

@implementation blockImage

-(instancetype)init{
 if (self = [super init]) {
      self = [[blockImage alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
      self.tag = 10;
      self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapActionWithBolck:)];
      [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

                        }
return self;
}


-(void)tapActionWithBolck:(void(^)(NSInteger idx))completion{

     completion(10);
  }
@end
```

and

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "blockImage.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

blockImage *img = [[blockImage alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:img];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use method like this with UITapGestureRecognizer

`-(void)tapActionWithBolck:(void(^)(NSInteger idx))completion;`

it should be like that

`-(void)tapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;`

or

`-(void)tapAction;`

If you want to use block on tap, you should keep it in variable (in init for example) and than call it in method. But keep in mind about *retain cycles.*